# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Hi I am first time working on Threads not sure If I am doing correct 
I am getting Error saying :

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" exception

```
   private void ImportProductStatsButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the currently selected manufacturer from the combo box
        var selected = comboBoxCorporation.SelectedItem;
        buttonProductStatsAndRetailerStats.Enabled = false;
        buttonSummariseRetailerStats.Enabled = false;
        buttonSummariseProductStats.Enabled = false;
       // Do we have one?
        if (selected != null)
        {
            // Extract the combo record
            var corporation = (ComboBoxCorporrationItem)selected;

            // Do we have one?
            if (corporation.Corporation != null)
            {
                // yes
                // Make this on a seperate thread so that the UI continues to work
                var thread = new Thread(MigrateProductStats);
              thread.Start(corporation.Corporation.Id); // This enables me to pick the manufacturer that we are summarizing for
             }
        }

    }

 private void MigrateProductStats(object corporationIdObj)
    {
       // after thread completion I need to Enable my buttons.
        buttonProductStatsAndRetailerStats.Enabled = true;
        buttonSummariseProductStats.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: You must use Control.Invoke see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx

Comment: Have you tried to type your exception to google and search?

Comment: @I4V I tried diffrent ways not able to find the solution . looked into http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html

Comment: @62071072 Strange since the first hit answers your problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
private void MigrateProductStats(object corporationIdObj)
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
       // after thread completion I need to Enable my buttons.
       buttonProductStatsAndRetailerStats.Enabled = true;
       buttonSummariseProductStats.Enabled = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. If I need to run two threads on one button click do I need to use Invoke?

Comment: You need invoke when changes a control from a thread tha not is the thread that created it. if you're not sure you can use `InvokeRequired` property that tell you if you need to use `Invoke`. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: it's safe to use `Invoke` even when not required.

Comment: Yes, it's just to know when you must use `Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Even better than `Control.Invoke` would be to use `BackgroundWorker` to handle threading for you.  It generates progress and completion events back on the UI thread to make UI updates easy.

If you're using C# 5, you can also use `async` to start the background processing and `await` to cause the UI updates to occur when processing completes.

Comment: Even better would be TPL (async/await)

Comment: @BenVoigt If you post a specific code, I can happily post an answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, `await`  doesn't work like `WaitHandle.WaitOne`

Comment: Thanks, added it as another suggestion in my answer, with the note about requiring newer C#.